# Printing star pattern

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to print a star pattern like the below

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But I got this instead.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*****
```

There seems to be a duplicate of the last line of star and I don't know why this is happening. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("*");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You put the line break at the wrong position. I would separate it from the writing of `*`, like

```java
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing one `*` at the start. It should be done like you are doing. Print a new line after 1 complete iteration of `For`, like this:

**CODE:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{
    //System.out.println("*");   // This line should not be here 
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();        // you can print new line after each nested-for compleletion
}
```

Comment: This answer is very similar to my answer. Why did you post it?

Comment: @JFMeier I was writing and checking the code and in the meantime you posted. I got to know it after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer (TL;DR)

Your line break was placed wrongly. Place your line break after the inner for-loop executes as shown below:

```
public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

### Detailed answer

First and foremost, you have to understand the difference between `System.out.print()` and `System.out.println()`. These two basically do the same thing: **They print out the argument passed into them.** However, there is one clear-cut difference: `System.out.println()` generates a new line feed after printing but `System.out.print` does not. To understand this concept, examine the example code below:

```
System.out.println("Tadaa");
System.out.print("Ta");
System.out.print("daa");
System.out.print("Stackoverflow");
```

The output of this would be:

> Tadaa
>
> Tadaa
>
> Stackoverflow

Using this logic, it would be easy to see where you went wrong. Intuitively, the breakage [`.println()`] is supposed to happen at the end of each iteration.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for the desired output

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{
    //System.out.println("*");   
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();        
}
```